# WPF Grid row height output doesn't correspond to code

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a strange thing going on with the WPF Grid.I am trying to build a specific layout, but the output row heights do not correspond to the ones in my code:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="105"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="59"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="Green"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Yellow"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="Blue"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Fill="Yellow"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Fill="Red"/>
   </Grid>
```

However, in the output the first row has a height of 131 pixels and the last row has a height of 74 pixels.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Well..you are specifying the height in device-independent units,so depending on the screen resolution it would be different pixels size. BTW, my advice is not using fixed sizes, it's better to use relative layouts

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a look at how WPF Units work.
WPF has device independent units, where one unit equals to 1/96th of an inch.
More info here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.height(v=VS.95).aspx